# Problems with left and right collision with as3 platformer

Tags: actionscript-3

Having problems with left and right hit collision, it detects it, but if you hold down for example right you can just pass through a wall without any real struggle, both thick and thin ones.

I know my collision detection isn't very good, but it's my first project som I'm trying something simple.

xFart is the speed in the x direction, fartKonstant is the constant you can change for higher or lower velocity, friksjonsKonstant is the friction in the game.

Would appreciate some help for this that isn't just a bandage :)

```
package AS
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Bane extends MovieClip
    {
        //Bevegelse variabler
        private var goUp:Boolean;
        private var goDown:Boolean;
        private var goLeft:Boolean;
        private var goRight:Boolean;

        //Fart variabler
        private var xScrollFart:Number = 10;
        private var yScrollFart:Number = 10;
        private var xFart:Number = 0;
        private var yFart:Number = 0;

        //Konstanter som kan endres
        private var minFart:Number = 0.5;
        private var maksFart:Number = 18;
        private var gravitasjonKonstant:Number = 1.8;
        private var hoppeKonstant:Number = 35;
        private var fartKonstant:uint = 4;
        private var friksjonKonstant:Number = 0.95;

        //Kollisjon
        private var upBumping:Boolean = false;  
        private var downBumping:Boolean = false;
        private var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
        private var rightBumping:Boolean = false

        //Kollisjonspunkter
        private var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(300 - 20, 300 - 40);
        private var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(300 + 20, 300 - 40);
        private var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(300, 300 - 80);
        private var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(300, 300);

        public function Bane()
        {
            goUp = false;
            goDown = false;
            goLeft = false;
            goRight = false;


            Constants.stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
            Constants.stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
            Constants.stageRef.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameListener);
        }

        private function keyDown(evt:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if(evt.keyCode==65) {goLeft=true} 
            if(evt.keyCode==68) {goRight=true} 
            if(evt.keyCode==87) {goUp=true} 
            if(evt.keyCode==83) {goDown=true} 
            if(evt.keyCode==37) {goLeft=true}
            if(evt.keyCode==38) {goUp=true}
            if(evt.keyCode==39) {goRight=true}
            if(evt.keyCode==40) {goDown=true}
        }


        private function keyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if(evt.keyCode==65) {goLeft=false} 
            if(evt.keyCode==68) {goRight=false} 
            if(evt.keyCode==87) {goUp=false} 
            if(evt.keyCode==83) {goDown=false} 
            if(evt.keyCode==37) {goLeft=false}
            if(evt.keyCode==38) {goUp=false}
            if(evt.keyCode==39) {goRight=false}
            if(evt.keyCode==40) {goDown=false}
        }



        //Kjører koden 29 ganger i sekundet, hver frame
        private function frameListener(e:Event)
        {
            //Kollisjon
            if(this.hitTestPoint(upBumpPoint.x, upBumpPoint.y, true))
            {
                trace("upBumping");
                upBumping = true;
            } 

            else 
            {
                upBumping = false;
            }

            if(this.hitTestPoint(downBumpPoint.x, downBumpPoint.y, true))
            {
                trace("downBump");
                downBumping = true;
            }

            else
            {
                downBumping = false;
            }

            if(this.hitTestPoint(leftBumpPoint.x, leftBumpPoint.y, true))
            {
                trace("leftBump");
                leftBumping = true;
            }

            else
            {
                leftBumping = false;
            }

            if(this.hitTestPoint(rightBumpPoint.x, rightBumpPoint.y, true))
            {
                trace("rightBump");
                rightBumping = true;
            }

            else
            {
                rightBumping = false;
            }

            if(leftBumping)
            {
                if(xFart < 0)
                {
                    xFart *= -0.5;
                }
            }

            if(rightBumping)
            {
                if(xFart > 0)
                {
                    xFart *= -0.5;
                }
            }

            if(upBumping)
            {
                if(yFart < 0)
                {
                    yFart *= -0.5;
                }
            }

            if(downBumping)
            {
                if(yFart > 0)
                {
                    yFart *= 0;
                }

                goDown = false;
            }

            if(goLeft == true)
            {
                xFart -= fartKonstant
            }

            if(goRight == true)
            {
                xFart += fartKonstant
            }

            if(goDown == true)
            {
                yFart += fartKonstant
            }

            if(Math.abs(xFart) <= minFart)
            {
                xFart = 0
            }

            if(xFart >= maksFart)
            {
                xFart = maksFart;
            }

            if(xFart <= (maksFart * -1))
            {
                xFart = maksFart * -1;
            }

            xFart *= friksjonKonstant;
            yFart *= friksjonKonstant;

            xScrollFart -= xFart;
            yScrollFart -= yFart;

            this.x = xScrollFart;
            this.y = yScrollFart;

            if(downBumping == false)
            {
                goUp = false;
                yFart += gravitasjonKonstant;
            }
                else if(downBumping == true)
            {
                if(goUp)
                {
                    yFart = hoppeKonstant * -1;
                } 

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not resolving collisions, that's the problem. Apart from detecting the fact of collision, you need to do something about colliding objects so they move out of collision.

Your **current** logic for every tick of simulation is as follows:

1. Check collisions with box bounds. (*Btw, why check opposite boundaries at the same time? Is it possible for the object to collide with left and right boundaries simultaneously?*)
2. If colliding, halve the speed and change direction along x/y axis to the opposite.
3. Change the speed according to some rules. (*Btw, why calculate opposite movement at the same time? Can your object actually move leftwards and rightwards simultaneously?*)
4. Move the object with its current speed.

The problem is, after the whole calculation is through, the object may still be in collision with the boundaries. You are missing the step, where you resolve collision by moving the object backwards along the path it came into collision after the previous step.

So, to fix the issue, you need to first move the object out of collision, when you detect one. That should be the second step in your calculation.

1. Check for collisions.
2. If detected, calculate **how much** the object collides with the obstacle, and move it back along the path it came, so it is no longer in collision.
3. ... the rest of your logic ...

The following links may prove useful:

- [Collision Detection and Response](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)
- [Broad-Phase Collision](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialB.html)

Comment: I have tried adding stuff like this.x -= 10 inside the "if(leftbumping)" but it didn't do anything, any other tips as to how I would do this?

Comment: Why is it 10 exactly? When you do `this.x = xScrollFart`, you may cause a collision with horizontal bounds. On next tick you need to **calculate** how much your object overlaps an obstacle and resolve collision accordingly. For example, if you detected a collision with `leftBumpPoint`, calculate the difference between `leftBumpPoint.x` and object `x` and move the object out of collision.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, will do that when I get it working, but the problem is it doesn't move it back any amount, I tried this.x -= 100 and stuff like this, but it did not work at all.